# Adding Prefix when creating an Index using Jredisearch

Tags: redis, spring-data-redis, redis-cluster, redisearch, redislabs

I use Jredisearch(com.redislabs:jredisearch:2.0.0) to store data in an Index. I want to add a prefix while creating the Index. I am able to add prefix using the below Redisearch command
FT.CREATE MyIndex ON HASH PREFIX 1 doc: SCHEMA name TEXT

But not able to find options for the same when writing in Java. I use the following code in Java,
client.createIndex(schema, Client.IndexOptions.defaultOptions());

Could anyone suggest how do we add Prefix when using Jredisearch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IndexDefinition` class has a `setPrefixes(...)` method which serves your purpose.

Note: You may have to create IndexDefinition using `new IndexDefinition()`.

Comment: I am able to set prefix in Jredisearch using IndexDefinition. Thank you.